# What does something :: Wrapper type mean in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I thought everything were functions in Haskell. For example:

```
sum :: Int -> Int
sum a b = a+b
```

But there are things like this:

```
tom :: Reader String String
```

what does this mean exactly? What is `tom`? A function that gets nothing and returns `Reader String String`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not everything is a function. For example,

```hs
x :: Char
x = 'w'
```

In the above example, `x` is not a function.

As for `Reader String String`, this is just a `newtype` alias of `String -> String`. To convert between the two, we have

`runReader :: Reader a b -> (a -> b)`
`reader :: (a -> b) -> Reader a b`

One can do nice things with `Reader`. For example, consider

```hs
average :: [Double] -> Double
average list = sum list / fromIntegral (length list)
```

Notice that we're passing `list` into two different functions. On the other hand, we can instead write

```hs
average :: [Double] -> Double
average = runReader $ do sumList <- reader sum
                         lengthList <- reader length
                         return (sumList / fromIntegral lengthList)
```

With the second definition of average, we can use the reader monad to eliminate the use of the `list` parameter entirely, instead using monadic `do` notation to eliminate the need for it.

Whether this makes code easier to understand or harder is an interesting question.

Comment: [yep, _just_ a newtype](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKtNn.png). :) :) --- also, `average = liftA2 (/) sum (fromIntegral . length)` or `average = do { s <- sum ; l <- length ; return (s / fromIntegral l) }` didn't even need to mention `reader`. :)

Comment: @WillNess Indeed. It's pretty rare that I would explicitly use `Reader` given that `(->) a` is already an isomorphic monad to `Reader a`. But the question specifically asked about `Reader`, so I gave an answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can probably see this as a function with no parameter - on some level that works ... for a while.

But a better answer is probably that no - not everything in Haskell is a *function* - there are just *values* as well and I'd call this a *value of type `Reader String String`*.

Same with `"Hello"` or `5`

---

**remark** incidentally `Reader` is only a wrapper around a function `Reader a b ~ a -> b` ;)

Answer (score 3):

> I thought everything were functions in Haskell.

Nope, in Haskell, a value is only a function if its type is `x -> y` for some types `x` and `y`.

Note that all functions in Haskell have exactly one input and one output. We *represent* functions of multiple inputs using *currying* e.g.:

```
x :: A
y :: B
z :: C

f       :: A -> B -> C -> D
f x     ::      B -> C -> D
f x y   ::           C -> D
f x y z ::                D

-- With explicit parentheses:

  f         :: A -> (B -> (C -> D))
  f x       ::       B -> (C -> D)
 (f x) y    ::             C -> D
((f x) y) z ::                  D
```

Casually, we would say this function takes 3 arguments, but this is just another way of *thinking* about the chain of unary functions; in reality, it can take *up to* 3 arguments—or even more, if `D` is a function type!

> ```
> tom :: Reader String String
> ```
>
> what does this mean exactly?

`tom` is a variable, or a binding, which is bound to a value of type `Reader String String`. This represents an *action* in the `Reader String` context. `tom` is just like a variable of any other type, including data types like `Int` or `String`:

```
count :: Int
count = length beans

beans :: String
beans = "beans"
```

Or other “action” types like `IO String`:

```
getLength :: IO String
getLength = do
  line <- getLine
  pure (length line)
```

> What is `tom`? A function that gets nothing and returns `Reader String String`?

It’s an action in the `Reader String` context; it represents a computation which may use a read-only value of type `String` (the first one) to produce a result of type `String` (the second).

It’s *not* a plain function itself, but incidentally a `Reader` action can be implemented as a `newtype` which just *contains* a function:

```
newtype Reader r a = Reader (r -> a)

runReader :: Reader r a -> r -> a
runReader (Reader f) = f
```

So `runReader tom` is a function of type `String -> String`. `Reader` allows you to avoid explicitly adding parameters to all of your functions that share some “configuration” or “environment” value (serving one of the roles of “dependency injection” in imperative/OOP languages).

Normally, when a type constructor is an instance of `Monad` (and therefore also `Applicative` and `Functor`), we refer to concrete values of that type as “actions”; some of these values, like `[a]`, `Maybe a`, and `Either e a`, are *also* “containers” of some kind. But others, like `Reader r a`, `State s a`, and `IO a`, are *only* actions—they don’t really have a “container” interpretation, they’re just descriptions of operations. You can *combine* these operations in a generic way with `>>=` / `<*>` / `pure` / `<$>`, but how you “run” an action depends on the particular type.

For `Reader` and `State`, there are `runReader` and `runState` functions, but for `IO`, there is no such function. Your Haskell code constructs an `IO ()` value (without side effects!) and the Haskell runtime evaluates this value for you if you assign it to `main`. This is the sense in which Haskell is “purely functional”.

In other words, an `IO String` isn’t a `String` “tagged” with the fact that it came from `IO`, it’s a *procedure* for producing a `String`, which is why you can’t “get the `a` out of an `IO a`”.

Comment: both container Functors and non-container Functors can just be seen as "producers".